# Swarm/Foursquare check-ins in twitter. How can i get CHECKIN_ID and SIGNATURE from Swarm url?

Tags: api, foursquare, checkin

The last few months, I am working with publicly available foursquare check-ins, gathered from twitter. Initially, I used an older dataset I had and now I try to process a more recent dataset. I noticed that most users now are using swarm for their check-ins but I have a problem with taking the CHECKIN_ID and SIGNATURE from those checkins. Many links from swarm (on twitter) have the following form: https://www.swarmapp.com/c/######## the last part is look like an id. My question is if there is a way to take CHECKIN_ID and SIGNATURE from those links in order to form a request to foursquare API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `resolve` endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/resolve) might be of help to you, but I don't think there's a way to get the the CHECKIN_ID and SIGNATURE any more.